# How do we change the title of this frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was playing around with some Tkinter code that I found online:

```
from Tkinter import * 

class ScrolledList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, options, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)                  
        self.makeWidgets(options)

    def handleList(self, event):
        index = self.listbox.curselection()            
        label = self.listbox.get(index)                
        self.runCommand(label)                         

    def makeWidgets(self, options):                    
        sbar = Scrollbar(self)
        list = Listbox(self, relief=SUNKEN)
        sbar.config(command=list.yview)                
        list.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)              
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                     
        list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)    
        pos = 0
        for label in options:                          
            list.insert(pos, label)                    
            pos = pos + 1

        list.bind('<Double-1>', self.handleList)       
        self.listbox = list
    def runCommand(self, selection):                   
        print 'You selected:', selection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = map((lambda x: 'Lumberjack-' + str(x)), range(20))
    ScrolledList(options).mainloop()
```

My question is: where is the frame created? I don't see anything like:

```
F1 = Tkinter.Frame()
```

Say if I wanted to add a label it would be:

```
label = Tkinter.Label(F1)
```

I'm looking into being able to add labels, and destroy the whole window when done (most likely add `frame.destroy()` line after `print selection` but I don't know what to address in that code).

Comment: You've picked a poor example as a starting point. The code should be explicitly creating the root window, but instead relies on implicit creation. That's a bad practice.

Comment: What do you want to add a label to?  You could put it inside `makeWidgets` if you want it to be part of the `ScrolledList`. @BryanOakley is correct that this isn't good code to learn from; note that it also shadows `list` in `makeWidgets`, which is bad practice.

Comment: When you ask "where is the frame created"? Are you asking about the window frame -- the border and window title, minimize and close buttons, etc? Unfortunately, as you can see in the code, Tkinter has a `Frame` class that is a container widget, but it has no relation to the border around the edge of the window.

Comment: I'm self learning so I may not get all your terminology @BryanOakley, but thanks for pointing out why this is a bad example. by frame I mean whatever I can address in destroy, and add label commands.

Comment: I'll try doing that @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Frame`s don't have titles; this works because `Tkinter` automagically creates a `Tk` instance the first time any widget is created and Tkinter detects that the root window hasn't been created yet (HT [@BryanOakley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807193/how-do-we-change-the-title-of-this-frame/30807322#comment49665891_30807322)). If you want to alter the window title, explicitly create a `Tk` instance and provide it as the `parent` to the `ScrolledList`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = map((lambda x: 'Lumberjack-' + str(x)), range(20))
    app = Tk()
    app.title('Demo')
    ScrolledList(options, parent=app)
    app.mainloop()
```

In many ways this is better, as it's easier to understand what's going on.

> my question is were [sic] is the frame created?

A `ScrolledList` **is** a `Frame`, that's the whole point of inheritance (`class ScrolledList(Frame):` means *"define a new class `ScrolledList` that inherits its behaviour from `Frame`"*). So the frame is created by `ScrolledList(...)`.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct. The `Tk` instance isn't automagically created when `mainloop` is called, it's created the first time any widget is created and Tkinter detects that the root window hasn't been created yet.

Comment: if nothing I learned a new word "automagically", I dont promise not stealing it.... before I find out myself I want to ask if app.destroy() is going to work if added to `def runCommand(self, selection):' code block.

Comment: answering my own question in the comments app.destroy() works!

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe points out, a `ScrolledList` [***is a***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Frame` because the class is derived from it. The base `Frame` class is initialized in the first line of the `ScrolledList.__init__()` method:

```
class ScrolledList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, options, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # <- calls base class constructor
          ...
```

Also, frames don't have a titles, so the closest way to have one is to add it to the window the frame is inside of. This can be done by explicitly creating the root window so you have a reference to it, use that to set its title, and then pass the window explicitly as the `ScrolledList`'s `parent`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('MyTitle')
    root.minsize(200, 200)  # also added so title is visible
    options = map((lambda x: 'Lumberjack-' + str(x)), range(20))
    ScrolledList(options, root)  # <- Passes root window as the parent
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of scrolllist with titel]

Comment: except for technical disagreement on where the base frame initializes, this is similar to the previous answer. +1 for root.minsize(200,200). Thanks!

Comment: There's no disagreement in the answers about where the base frame initializes — sounds like you may be confusing `Frame`s and windows again. @jonrsharpe's answer talks about `Tk` instances and root windows, not `Frame` (or `ScrollList`) instances. Having an explicit reference to the containing window basically just give you a lot more control over it. Another real-life example would be to use `root.iconbitmap()` to change the icon that is shown in the upper left of the window next to the title.